# Winform : Set Password for SQL Server connection string in app.config programatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, passwords, connection-string

I am trying to develop a closed system window form application. The problem I am facing is that how should I make my application data secure because it contains very sensitive data.

**Problem**

I want to set the password in the connection String programmatically.

```
<add name="salary_slipEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TFSSERVER;initial catalog=salary_slip;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now is there a way I can set the password in the `app.config` file programmatically via login form? For better understanding I am adding a screenshot.

I am thinking something like this.

[image]

Comment: here the SQl Password is for the Connection string
and username password are for admin authentication. They are checked from on of the table inside the database

Comment: why dont you want appconfig can you imagine recompile because password change

Comment: I want app config. I just want to set the password field programitically

Comment: You could find this article a starting point http://kkryczka.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/dynamically-create-entity-framework-connection-string/

Comment: @user3859356 its just a string you can build it yourself `"User ID=" + username ";Password=" +passwd;`"

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I implemented it on my own.. Just had to amke some changes in model.contect.cs , app.config and program.cs

Answer (score 0):

To be precise build up the connection string using StringBuilder class. When all components appended to the stringbuilder entity convert it ToString() to form your actual connectionstring